# question about half closed inteval $[a+1/n,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I can't find a resource at this moment that can answer me this question and I'm having some doubts.

what is $ \bigcup_{1}^{n} [1/n ,2)$ as $n \to \infty$

Is it $(0,2)$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The geometric intuition that gave you this can be turned into a formal proof.  The more general question of the title is trickier, for $a+1/1$ could be $\ge b$.

Comment: You probably meant to write something like $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} [1/k ,2)$, though.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: Let $r$ be an arbitrary real and let $A =\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}{[\frac{1}{k},r)}$. Then  $A = (0,r)$.

Proof: The claim is clear if $r$ is non-positive, since $\emptyset = \emptyset$. Suppose $r > 0$. One can see that $A \subseteq (0,r)$ (if $x \in A$, then $x \in [\frac{1}{m},r) \subseteq (0,r)$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$). Now suppose $y \in (0,r)$. By the Archimedian Property of the reals, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y > \frac{1}{n}$. Since $y < r$, we have that $y \in [\frac{1}{n},r) \subseteq A$. Thus $(0,r) \subseteq A$, and hence $A = (0,r)$.

Let $r = 2$.